# Rotate text inside a path

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

I have text inside a path as below. I want the text to be at an angle, but using the transform tool rotates the path itself and not the text. How can I change the angle of the text, leaving the path where it is? I'm using CS6. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to rotate the text alone, but there is a workaround.

Add another object such as a rectangle on top of the text, and group the text filled shape and this object. Rotate the group until the text is at the desired angle. Ungroup, and delete the extra object you made. Then rotate the shape back to its original position. You can use some guides if you need accuracy.

An example

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, many thanks!